# how to set width of column dynamically in android tablelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a tablelayout, where columns are added dynamically. I'm unable to set width of the column/TextView dynamically.

This is my code:

```
TableLayout employeeTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

    TableRow header = new TableRow(this);
    header.setId(100);
    header.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
    //header.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    TextView empCodeHeader = new TextView(this);
    empCodeHeader.setId(200);
    empCodeHeader.setText("Employee Code");
    empCodeHeader.setTextSize(16);
    empCodeHeader.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
    //empCodeHeader.setWidth(200);
    header.addView(empCodeHeader);

    TextView empNameHeader = new TextView(this);
    empNameHeader.setId(201);
    empNameHeader.setText("Employee Name");
    empNameHeader.setTextSize(16);
    empNameHeader.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
    //empNameHeader.setWidth(300);
    header.addView(empNameHeader);
```

I'm able to set using setWidth, but i want to set it dynamically, say 30% for column1 and 70% for column2.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) for set height and width dynamically.